# Calling UWP OCR sample from WPF Application with UWPDesktop nuget package

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I am calling Windows 10 API from my WPF application. I have installed "UWPDesktop" Nuget package also.
I have called UWP OCR API from WPF application, After running code, I am getting an
Exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The process has no package identity. 
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)'

I have just written this code in my wpf application.
And also added UWPDesktop nugget package to access UWP API.

var ocrEngine = Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(new Windows.Globalization.Language("en"));

```
        var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\test.png");

        using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            // Create image decoder.
            var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

            // Load bitmap.
            var bitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

            // Extract text from image.
            OcrResult result = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(bitmap);

            // Return recognized text.
            Trace.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

I am getting exception at first line.

What is this exception and why it occurs?

Comment: you should consider adding some code in order to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

That error says that OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage can be called only from a UWP app (which runs in an app container) and not in a desktop app (which doesn't run in a container). If you look at god API document you'll find a [DualApiPartition attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute) on Windows Runtime methods API that can be called in both UWP and desktop contexts. The OcrEngine methods don't have this attribute so can't be called from desktop apps.

Your options will be to use a different OCR package or to call it from inside an app context. For the latter look into packaging the WPF app as a UWP app with the [Windows Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)

Comment: What do you mean by 'god API document'? The attribute isn't listed on the Microsoft Docs site. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.ocr.ocrengine.trycreatefromlanguage#definition

Comment: Ah sorry, I now know what you mean. The BluetoothLEDevice for instance has that attribute defined in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice